# qt getting mouse event by mousearea and textfield

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I tried to make text, which allow selection, but on double click I want, to expand some other elements (I think it's not important, so replaced with simple `console.log()`).

```
Rectangle {
    TextEdit {
        readOnly: true
        text: "Example text!"
    }
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        propagateComposedEvents: true
        onClicked: {
            mouse.accepted = true
            console.log('clicked')
        }
        onPressed: mouse.accepted = false;  ### this true|false switches behavior 
    }
}
```

But than I change `onPressed` handler I switches between "selectable text but not working `onClicked` handler" and "working `onClicked` handler but not selectable text".

Comment: When you set `mouse.accepted = false` in `onPressed` you declare that this `MouseArea` shall not receive any other events of this chain of events, so the `onClicked` should not be executed.

Comment: However it should be quite easy to reimplement the selection with the methods provided by the `TextEdit`. Mainly `positionAt(x,y)` to get the position you clicked at, and then released again, to then use `select(startPos, endPos)` to perform the selection.

Comment: You can try to accept the mouse event and forward it to the TextEdit: `textEdit.pressed(mouse)`